# htaccess to add ?query=string to specific url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get a `.htaccess` rewrite rule to work. I'm sure this should be easy but I just can't get it right!

I need to add `?query=string` to a specific URL pattern so:

```
www.example.com/downloads/file
```

Becomes:

```
www.example.com/downloads/file?query=string
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*) downloads/$1?query=string
```

But it's not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? What exactly is happening? What are you trying to do? Internal rewrite or external redirect?

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks OK, except you might need to include the `L` flag to prevent further rewritting:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*) downloads/$1?query=string [L]
```

And if this is intended to be an external redirect then you'll need to make the *substitution* absolute or root-relative and include the `R` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*) /downloads/$1?query=string [R=302,L]
```